# Perché “avere culo” significa “essere fortunati”?

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Leggendo [questa domanda su Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/italy/comments/8qky0w/perch%C3%A9_avere_culo_%C3%A8_sinonimo_con_avere_fortuna/) mi rendo conto che non so perché colloquialmente, con una diffusione molto ampia, si dica “avere culo” (e varianti eufemistiche che accennano a “c...” o al “lato B” o alla “fortuna con la C maiuscola”) per dire di essere fortunati.

Nelle risposte a quella domanda si accenna a teorie curiose ma senza fonti. Qualcuno ha risposte più fondate?

EDIT: Giusto, tecnicamente uno dei partecipanti a quel filone su Reddit cita una “fonte”, ma cercherei qualcosa di più solido di “parolacce.org”.

Comment: Ritengo che "botta di culo" costituisca l'imprevisto sostegno della fortuna e non c'entri nulla con il fallo: la fortuna proietta in avanti il fortunato, spingendolo forte, facendolo (metaforicamente) balzare su un possente cavallo ("stare a cavallo").
La fonte indiretta è Virgilio, che associa il Cavallo alle fortune di Cartagine: Didone sceglie il sito della Città là ove rinviene un teschio di cavallo.

Comment: Nel spagnolo anche ‘tener culo’ == ‘tener suerte’!!! Forse l'hanno ereditata da noi. la mia ipotesi è che derivi dallo spagnolo. Se ti interessa, ti risponderò

Comment: la mia ipotesi è che derivi dallo spagnolo argentino, perche qua è emerso a partire dal 1920. Se ti interessa, ti risponderò

Comment: Sapevo che qs espressione è stata estrapolata da una citazione di (mi pare) Aristofane...che più o meno diceva..."la fortuna arride ai bei culi".
Anni fa proprio su internet, trovai un riscontro...ad oggi però non lo trovo più, c'è qualcuno che può aiutarmi a trovare un riscontro? Grazie

Answer (score 1):

Sebbene la fonte non sembri essere di prima categoria, ho trovato comunque in [questo articolo](https://www.parolacce.org/2014/05/04/perche-culo-significa-fortuna/) un interessante ragionamento, di cui riporto i passi principali:

> Sul Web ho trovato due spiegazioni su questo curioso modo di dire. La
>   prima ricollega l’espressione alla pederastia dei Romani: “i bei
>   giovani dai glutei appetitosi venivano molto richiesti dai Romani che,
>   per poterli possedere sessualmente, li ricoprivano di regali. Così,
>   avere un bel posteriore, per un ragazzo, era indizio di una vita più
>   fortunata rispetto ai propri coetanei”.

...

> L’altra spiegazione che circola sul Web fa riferimento a un fatto
>   storico: le forche caudine, ovvero l’umiliazione dei Romani sconfitti
>   dai Sanniti nel 321 a.C. Secondo alcuni, alla fine, i Romani furono
>   sodomizzati uno a uno e “chi aveva un ano più grande (sic!) soffriva
>   meno, quindi era più fortunato” .

Entrambe però non sembrano avere riscontro storico per cui la spiegazione del modo di dire deve essere un’altra.

> La letteratura non ci viene in aiuto: «l’espressione ‘avere culo’ è
>   abbastanza recente» dice il lessicografo Giovanni Casalegno. «Nel
>   “Grande dizionario della lingua italiana” del 1964 è presente, ma non
>   si cita alcuna fonte letteraria». Ma se la letteratura non ci aiuta,
>   può venirci in soccorso la scienza.

...

> L’etologo Desmond Morris ha dedicato diverse pagine all’argomento, nel
>   bellissimo libro “L’uomo e i suoi gesti” “Pare che le grosse e rotonde
>   natiche femminili siano un antico segnale di richiamo sessuale,
>   l’equivalente umano del gonfiore delle femmine degli altri primati”
>   scrive Morris. “Per lanciare un segnale sessuale al maschio, la
>   scimmia femmina gli presenta il posteriore nel modo più cospicuo
>   possibile. Nelle scimmie di tutte le specie, questo gonfiore aumenta e
>   diminuisce secondo il ciclo mensile della femmina, raggiungendo la
>   dimensione massima nel periodo dell’ovulazione.

...

> Dunque, tirando le somme: i glutei sono simbolo di femminilità, sesso,
>   fecondità, attrattività, felicità (che, etimologicamente, significa
>   fecondità). Per il linguista Ottavio Lurati,  le parti anatomiche
>   collegate alla riproduzione (quindi non solo il sedere, ma anche il
>   fallo e la vagina) hanno un valore vitale così alto che sono usate
>   simbolicamente “come forze apotropaiche per allontanare il dolore, la
>   magia, il male, il malocchio: dunque, aver culo significa aver
>   fortuna”. La spiegazione è plausibile, visto che la sessualità è vita
>   e come tale scaccia la morte.

Comment: Grazie, ma questa è proprio la stessa “fonte” che citano su Reddit. Mi scuso per non averla menzionata prima nella mia domanda.

Comment: Comunque uno spunto interessante è in quella frase attribuita a Casalegno. Chissà da dove è tratta: vedo che tra l'altro è coautore di _Brutti, fessi e cattivi. Lessico della maldicenza italiana_, che potrebbe essere interessante da questo punto di vista.

Comment: Le prime due possibilità mi sembrano vergognosamente fasulle.

Comment: Va osservato, che il gestaccio con cui spesso si accompagna l'espressione "che culo", non sembra riferirsi alla rotondità delle natiche, quanto a un esteso impiego a scopo di piacere dello stesso. Potrebbe trattarsi di una nota di biasimo omofoba, eventualmente scherzosa, per chi è molto fortunato.

Comment: Non escluderei che l'espressione possa nascere dal fatto che in passato la pinguità fosse considerata un segno di agiatezza economica (vedi, ad esempio, il detto *"omo de panza, omo de sostanza*") e, per esteso, di fortuna. Da qui potrebbe derivare l'uso di "avere culo" (con un implicito "abbondante/grosso") per indicare l'avere fortuna.

Answer (score 1):

Noto che è stata citata sopra una dichiarazione del Dottore Casalegno:  «L’espressione ‘avere culo’ è abbastanza recente. Nel “Grande dizionario della lingua italiana” del 1964 è presente, ma non si cita alcuna fonte letteraria».

Non ne dubito, ma posso attestare, come italoamericano, che l'espressione "avere culo" (ovvero "avere culone"), per indicare la condizione di esser fortunato, era piuttosto comune a casa nostra a Nuova York negli anni '60 e '70.  I miei erano ciociari di Sora e i suoi dintorni (Fontechiari e Vicalvi), emigrati dall'Italia all'inizio del novecento e non ritornati in Italia fino a molti anni dopo.  Quindi, deduco che l'espressione sia stato ben consolidata, almeno in qualche dialetto d'Italiano, molto prima degli anni '60.

Per favore, scusate il mio povero italiano, ma sono molto interessato a questa discussione.